# Horizontal Grand Total in Pivot Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query working:

```
      select cap_idPlanoContasFin  , [3684],[2234],[2] ,  
      from 
      (
      select cap_idPlanoContasFin,cap_idempresa,sum(cap_valorfatura) 
          as Stotal    
          from erp_ContasPagar 
       group by cap_idPlanoContasFin , cap_idEmpresa 

       ) as sourcetable
       pivot 
       (sum(Stotal)for cap_idEmpresa in ([3684],[2234],[2])
       )as pivottable;
```

This query returns:

```
      cap_idPlanoContasFin  3684          2234       2
                      3 9000          NULL      NULL
                     10 1057840,68    NULL  1865081,35
                     11 NULL          7283,1    591,9
                     12 NULL          NULL  178914,45
                     13 9305,07       1117,6    500
                     14 NULL          59333,5   34611,74
```

I want to put in the same query the Horizontal Total 
Example:

```
      cap_idPlanoContasFin  3684      2234            2           Total
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------      
                       13   9305,07    1117,6   500          10922,67
```

How to make this? I have read something with `UNION`.

Comment: Its not clear how you are getting the totals row? Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model and then clarify your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to group your data beforehand: the PIVOT clause will do that for you. So you can remove the GROUP BY clause and change the `SUM()`'s argument in PIVOT accordingly:

```
select cap_idPlanoContasFin, [3684], [2234], [2]  
from 
(
  select cap_idPlanoContasFin, cap_idempresa, cap_valorfatura
    from erp_ContasPagar 
  group by cap_idPlanoContasFin , cap_idEmpresa
) as sourcetable
pivot 
(
  sum(cap_valorfatura) for cap_idEmpresa in ([3684], [2234], [2])
) as pivottable;
```

To add a total column, you could use a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) `SUM()` like this:

```
select cap_idPlanoContasFin, [3684], [2234], [2], Total
from 
(
  select cap_idPlanoContasFin, cap_idempresa, cap_valorfatura,
         sum(cap_valorfatura) over (partition by cap_idPlanoContasFin) as Total
    from erp_ContasPagar 
) as sourcetable
pivot 
(
  sum(cap_valorfatura) for cap_idEmpresa in ([3684], [2234], [2])
) as pivottable;
```

Note, however, that if your `sourcetable` includes rows with `cap_idEmpresa` values other than those listed in the PIVOT clause, the corresponding `cap_valorfatura` values will be added up too. So you might want to filter the `sourcetable` row set before pivoting, like this:

```
select cap_idPlanoContasFin, [3684], [2234], [2], Total
from 
(
  select cap_idPlanoContasFin, cap_idempresa, cap_valorfatura,
         sum(cap_valorfatura) over (partition by cap_idPlanoContasFin) as Total
    from erp_ContasPagar 
   where cap_idempresa in (3684, 2234, 2)
) as sourcetable
pivot 
(
  sum(cap_valorfatura) for cap_idEmpresa in ([3684], [2234], [2])
) as pivottable;
```

Comment: That s work perfect Andriy M, many thanks, i m gonna upload the schema in sqlFiddle later, other question where i write the order by?? i want to order the output in order by cap_idPlanoContasFin

Comment: Just put it at the end of the query, after `as pivottable`, i.e. like this: `... as pivottable ORDER BY cap_idPlanoContasFin;`.

Comment: Yes, just add something like `[22345] + [2] AS Subtotal` to the SELECT column list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all , this is the final query :

```
 select cap_idPlanoContasFin, plc_classificador, plc_nomeConta,[3684], [2234], [2], 
 isnull ([2234],0) + isnull ([2],0) AS Subtotal ,Total    
 from 
 (
 select A.cap_idempresa, A.cap_idPlanoContasFin,  A.cap_valorfatura, 
 B.plc_classificador , B.plc_nomeConta,
 sum(A.cap_valorfatura) over (partition by A.cap_idPlanoContasFin) as Total
 from erp_ContasPagar A /*where cap_idempresa in (3684, 2234, 2)*/ 
 inner  join  tbl_PlanoFinanceiro B on A.cap_idPlanoContasFin = B.plc_id
 )  as sourcetable
 pivot 
 (
 sum(cap_valorfatura) for cap_idEmpresa in ([3684], [2234], [2])
 ) as pivottable;
```

I need use isnull to change NULL by o to sume subtotal . Thanks again by the help