# SQL Server Pivot Row Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have the below pivot code that works fine.  However, how do I include a row total i.e. a sum of the recorded amount for each account over the course of the year?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT [Account],[AccountDesc], CONVERT(CHAR(4), AccDate, 100) as [Month], [RecordedAmount]
FROM [tblGLS215_2016_2017]
WHERE [Employee] = @Employee
) AS s
PIVOT
(
SUM ([RecordedAmount])
FOR [Month] in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec)
) As pvt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418103/horizontal-grand-total-in-pivot-table-sql

Comment: The comment above looks like it will acheive the result; but you can also do something like `SELECT pvt.*
,Isnull(pvt.jan,0)
+Isnull(pvt.feb,0)
+Isnull(pvt.mar,0)
+Isnull(pvt.apr,0)
+Isnull(pvt.may,0)
+Isnull(pvt.jun,0)
+Isnull(pvt.jul,0)
+Isnull(pvt.aug,0)
+Isnull(pvt.sept,0)
+Isnull(pvt.oct,0)
+Isnull(pvt.nov,0)
as YearTotal
FROM (`

Comment: @WEI_DBA The link given does not resemble my pivot - he has a group-by and I am still need to sum for each month so I have rejected that answer

Comment: @Aron where do I put the select pvt * - I'm using a Select * from then PIVOT within, do I need to add another another sub select for the total?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested this is the final working solution:

```
SELECT pvt.* ,Isnull(pvt.jan,0) +Isnull(pvt.feb,0) +Isnull(pvt.mar,0) +Isnull(pvt.apr,0) +Isnull(pvt.may,0) +Isnull(pvt.jun,0) +Isnull(pvt.jul,0) +Isnull(pvt.aug,0) +Isnull(pvt.sept,0) +Isnull(pvt.oct,0) +Isnull(pvt.nov,0) as YearTotal
FROM (
SELECT [Account],[AccountDesc], CONVERT(CHAR(4), AccDate, 100) as [Month], [RecordedAmount]
FROM [tblGLS215_2016_2017]
WHERE [Employee] = @Employee
) AS s
pivot (
SUM ([RecordedAmount])
FOR [Month] in (May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)
) As pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

this would also work for you and might perform better

```
SELECT  [Account],
        [AccountDesc],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Jan' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Jan],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Feb' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Feb],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Mar' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Mar],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Apr' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Apr],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'May' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [May],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Jun' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Jun],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Jul' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Jul],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Aug' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Aug],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Sept' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Sept],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Oct' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Oct],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Nov' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Nov],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 'Dec' THEN [RecordedAmount] END) AS [Dec],
        SUM([RecordedAmount]) AS [Total]
FROM    (
            SELECT  [Account],
                    [AccountDesc],
                    CONVERT(CHAR(4),AccDate,100) AS [Month],
                    [RecordedAmount]
            FROM    [tblGLS215_2016_2017]
            WHERE   [Employee] = @Employee 
        ) t
GROUP BY [Account],
        [AccountDesc]
```

works the same as pivot but gives a little more control when including extra information.